# Inside function How do I use "this.http (Restful)"?

Tags: angular, rest, http, typescript, smartadmin

I created an HTTP utilities service and a messaging service.

In the message box, ask the user for consent. And when I agree, I have trouble using the HTTP utility service.

I do not know how to use the HTTP utility service inside the function.

Please help me.

### [ Message.service.ts ]

```
FullScreenConfirm(title, content, fs, ff){
    this.notificationService.smartMessageBox({
        title : title,
        content : content,
        buttons : '[No][Yes]'
    }, (ButtonPressed) => {
        if (ButtonPressed == "Yes") {
            fs(); //success Method
        } else if(ButtonPressed == "No"){
            ff(); //fail Method
        }
    });
}
```

I purchased the "SmartAdmin" template.

So you can use "notificationService".

### [ appManagement.component.ts ]

```
appDelete(appName) {
    this.messageBoxService.FullScreenConfirm("DELETE", "Are you sure you want to delete?",
    function(){
        this.http.delete(this.http.serverURL + "/delete/" + this.appList.id)
        .then((res) => {
            console.log("SUCCESS");
        });
    },
    function(){
        console.log("FAIL");
    })
}
```

### [ RESULT ]

"ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'http' of undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic `this` scoping issue. With the code in the question, `this` is isolated to the function it is in and thus has no access to the `this` object you're trying to access.

To fix this, you'll need to assign a variable to `this`

```
appDelete(appName) {
    var self = this;

    this.messageBoxService.FullScreenConfirm("DELETE", "Are you sure you want to delete?",
    function(){
        self.http.delete(this.http.serverURL + "/delete/" + this.appList.id)
        .then((res) => {
            console.log("SUCCESS");
        });
    },
    function(){
        console.log("FAIL");
    })
}
```

here i assign a reference variable to `this` named "self" so we can access it within our function.

NOTE: You can get around this quirk by using ES6's [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

That would look something like this:

```
appDelete(appName) {
    this.messageBoxService.FullScreenConfirm("DELETE", "Are you sure you want to delete?",
    () => {
        this.http.delete(this.http.serverURL + "/delete/" + this.appList.id)
        .then((res) => {
            console.log("SUCCESS");
        });
    },
    (err) => {
        console.log(err || "FAIL");
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you ... ^^ !  // "()" I first knew this was ES6.

Answer (score 0):

First you must import it `import { Http } from @angular/http`, declare it in your constructor `private http : Http` then you can use it in any fonction like this `this.http.post(...)`.
You should checkout documentation for more details https://angular.io/guide/http

Answer (score 0):

Inject your dependencies inside your constructor

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, RequestOptions, Response, URLSearchParams  } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class MyService{

  params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();


  constructor(
    private http: Http
  ) { }

}
```

and change your function to ES6 arrow function which binds to `this`

```
 function () {
   //code here
 }


 ES6 arrow function

 () => {
   //code here
 }
```